# Setting Account Lockout Threshold in MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server

I have to set **Account Lockout Threshold** to some specific value In MSSQL Server 2008. How can i do this? I have googled and not able to find the exact solution how to do it.
Whether SQL server account uses default Windows threshold to lock the sql account?

Thanks in advance...
Santhosha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 uses the password policy enforcement settings from the domain or local machine. To set it you need to edit the domain policy that applies to the SQL server if the SQL server is joined to a domain, or edit the local machine policy if the SQL server is not joined to a domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can not. SQL Server has no account lockout threshhold for it's user management. For trusted connections it also has none - because you have to come through a trusted connection, which means wherever you got your trust from (outside) the value was taken into account.

Comment: Then how the behavior "Account Locked out" is  decided?

Answer (score 0):

SQL server has 2 possible authentication modes, Mixed and Windows authentication only.  In mixed mode accounts may be stored inside sql server and may have a different complexity setting as well as logins using windows accounts.  In windows authentication only windows accounts can be used and user account information is not stored in sql server.  Regardless of authentication type account lockout behaviour is defined by the security policy that affects the account in question for local accounts local ecurity policy applies and for domain accounts domain group policy applies